# uitableview:In a same Row selected button should checked and remaining buttons should be unchecked automaticallyy

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i am doing feedback form using UITableview in that using custom checkbox for selection.In a UITableviewcell i placed four static buttons for options like,**Very 
Good**,**Good**,**Average**,**Below Average**.

What i want is,i want to select only one button checked in a row, if i select another button checked automatically previous selected button should be unchecked.

Example: In same row suppose if i select **Very Good** first again i selected **Average** , previous selected **Very Good** should be unchecked.

Check My code Below for reference:

This is in cellforrowatindexpath

```
[cell.R1_BTN setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Touch_G.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.R1_BTN addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
cell.R1_BTN.tag=1;
```

Click event here..

```
-(void)BtnClicked:(id)sender
{
//Need Code Here..
}
```

[image: shared my screen once :]

updated code for reference..

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return [GNM count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return  [GNM objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   if ([[NM objectAtIndex:section] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
   {
     return [[NM objectAtIndex:section] count];
   }
   else
   {
     return 1;
   }
```

}

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 FeedBackFormTVC *cell = [FeedBack_TV dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.FBName_LBL.text = [[NM objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]
? [[NM objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
: [NM objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

// below for assigning code action event..
....
....
...

}
```

I tried using Tags,but i didn't get what i want, pls help me.. thanks in Advance.

Comment: use this library to group button https://github.com/frederik-jacques/TNRadioButtonGroup

Comment: for easyness use didselect and diddeselect delegate methods of uitableview.

Comment: You could use a `UISegmentedControl`.

Comment: @Vinodh : i tried bit complication in views.thanks for info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should use model to set for UITableViewCell. Your model's .h file like :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef enum : NSInteger {
    UNKNOWN = 0,
    VERY_GOOD = 1,
    GOOD = 2,
    AVERAGE = 3,
    BELOW_AVERAGE = 4
}RangeMark;

@interface CellModel : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, assign)    RangeMark range;

@end
```

.m file like:

```
#import "CellModel.h"

@implementation CellModel

@end
```

than you should init a table cell with .xib file looks like:
[image]

and its .h file like :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CellModel.h"

@interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *veryGoodButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *goodButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *averageButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *belowAverageButton;

- (void)setupCellWithModel:(CellModel*)model;

@end
```

its .m file like :

```
#import "TableViewCell.h"

@implementation TableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)setupCellWithModel:(CellModel *)model {

    if(model.range == VERY_GOOD) {
        self.veryGoodButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    else if(model.range == GOOD) {
        self.goodButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
    else if(model.range == AVERAGE) {
        self.averageButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    }
    else if(model.range == BELOW_AVERAGE) {
        self.belowAverageButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
}

- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.veryGoodButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    self.goodButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    self.averageButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    self.belowAverageButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
}

@end
```

Finally your view controller .h file should look like :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TableViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

and .m file should look like :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
    NSMutableArray<CellModel*> *modelList;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 600;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

    modelList = [NSMutableArray<CellModel*> new];

    for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
        CellModel *cellModel = [[CellModel alloc] init];
        cellModel.range = UNKNOWN;
        [modelList addObject:cellModel];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    [cell setupCellWithModel:[modelList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.veryGoodButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.goodButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.averageButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.belowAverageButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    [cell.veryGoodButton addTarget:self action:@selector(veryGood:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell.goodButton addTarget:self action:@selector(good:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell.averageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(average:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell.belowAverageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(belowAverage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;

    return nil;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return modelList.count;
}

- (void) veryGood:(UIButton*)sender {
    [modelList objectAtIndex: sender.tag].range = VERY_GOOD;
    [self setCellDynamicly:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0] withCellModel:[modelList objectAtIndex: sender.tag]];
}

- (void) good:(UIButton*)sender {
    [modelList objectAtIndex: sender.tag].range = GOOD;
    [self setCellDynamicly:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0] withCellModel:[modelList objectAtIndex: sender.tag]];
}

- (void) average:(UIButton*)sender {
    [modelList objectAtIndex: sender.tag].range = AVERAGE;
    [self setCellDynamicly:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0] withCellModel:[modelList objectAtIndex: sender.tag]];
}

- (void) belowAverage:(UIButton*)sender {
    [modelList objectAtIndex: sender.tag].range = BELOW_AVERAGE;
    [self setCellDynamicly:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0] withCellModel:[modelList objectAtIndex: sender.tag]];
}

- (void)setCellDynamicly:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath withCellModel:(CellModel*)cellModel {
    TableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell prepareForReuse];
    [cell setupCellWithModel:cellModel];
}

@end
```

that s all :)

At the end app looks like :

[image]

Comment: Good effort, everything is fine. but i have many sections which comes from response like below :  (
Service Speed,
Good Service,
Confirmation quality,
)
,
(
Check In,
Happy on their Service,
Courtesey,
)
,
(
Front office & reception,
Overall Quality of Room,
Check,
)
,
(
Room Decor,
Time taken to serveTime taken to serveTime taken t,
Bathroom,
Facilities in the Room,
)
,
(
Overall Comments,
Will you come back again
)
,
Guest Satisfaction Ratings
)     ...  how to pass this in for-loop[viewdidload].. previous i loaded tableview by using iskindofclass

Comment: can you share a mockup about this? or a screen shot with dummy data? there are only five cells on your tableview, am I right?

Comment: edited my question, pls check screenshot..your code is working fine for single section.but i have multiple sections data comes dynamically. pls help me..

Comment: if these items are static, just assign cell class to the prototype cell

Comment: everything comes from response, section header and rows. its not static, that the problem here. if its static your codes will work perfectly.. but bad luck here

Comment: can you share the API response from the online tool or using postman . It will be helpful in creating model and help you in fixing the issue

Comment: @GökhanAydın : yes, thanks for update.i have one doubt, pls check my code, i updated.. in that you will find GNM and NM array , GNM contains section header names and NM contains rows related to sections.. everything comes from response like i posted in first comment .. here you added items to sectionTitleList and modelList static. but ,how it will work in my case..pls give me idea..

Answer (score 1):

yes this will be a solution for you, at least I hope like this :)

first of all create a custom button .h file like this :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomButton : UIButton

@property (assign) NSInteger sectionTag;
@property (assign) NSInteger rowTag;

@end
```

custom button .m file like this :

```
#import "CustomButton.h"

@implementation CustomButton

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

then I changed a few things in TableViewCell .h file like this :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CellModel.h"
#import "CustomButton.h"

@interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet CustomButton *veryGoodButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet CustomButton *goodButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet CustomButton *averageButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet CustomButton *belowAverageButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *itemLabel;

- (void)setupCellWithModel:(CellModel*)model;

@end
```

TableViewCell .m file like this :

```
#import "TableViewCell.h"

@implementation TableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)setupCellWithModel:(CellModel *)model {

    if(model.range == VERY_GOOD) {
        self.veryGoodButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    else if(model.range == GOOD) {
        self.goodButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
    else if(model.range == AVERAGE) {
        self.averageButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    }
    else if(model.range == BELOW_AVERAGE) {
        self.belowAverageButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    [self.itemLabel setText:model.itemText];
}

- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.veryGoodButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    self.goodButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    self.averageButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    self.belowAverageButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
}
```

and its .xib like this :

[image]

on the other side, there is only one change on CellModel .h file like this :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef enum : NSInteger {
    UNKNOWN = 0,
    VERY_GOOD = 1,
    GOOD = 2,
    AVERAGE = 3,
    BELOW_AVERAGE = 4
}RangeMark;

@interface CellModel : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, assign)    RangeMark range;
@property(nonatomic, copy)      NSString* itemText;

- (id)initWith:(NSString*)itemText withRangeMark:(RangeMark)range;

@end
```

and its .m file like this :

```
#import "CellModel.h"

@implementation CellModel

- (id)initWith:(NSString*)itemText withRangeMark:(RangeMark)range {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.itemText = itemText;
        self.range = range;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

finally view controller .h file same but .m like this :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
    NSMutableArray *modelList;
    NSMutableArray<NSString*> *sectionTitleList;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 600;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

    sectionTitleList = [NSMutableArray<NSString*> new];
    [sectionTitleList addObject:@"RESERVATION"];
    [sectionTitleList addObject:@"FRONT DESK"];
    [sectionTitleList addObject:@"CASHIER"];
    [sectionTitleList addObject:@"HOUSE KEEPING"];

    modelList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 4];

    [modelList insertObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[[CellModel alloc] initWith:@"Service Speed" withRangeMark:UNKNOWN],[[CellModel alloc] initWith:@"Good Speed" withRangeMark:UNKNOWN],[[CellModel alloc] initWith:@"Confirmation Quality" withRangeMark:UNKNOWN],[[CellModel alloc] initWith:@"Quick Service in Reservetion" withRangeMark:UNKNOWN],nil] atIndex:0];

    [modelList insertObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[[CellModel alloc] initWith:@"Check In" withRangeMark:UNKNOWN],[[CellModel alloc] initWith:@"Happy on Their Service" withRangeMark:UNKNOWN],[[CellModel alloc] initWith:@"Coutesey" withRangeMark:UNKNOWN],[[CellModel alloc] initWith:@"Quick Service at Check In" withRangeMark:UNKNOWN],nil] atIndex:1];

    [modelList insertObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[[CellModel alloc] initWith:@"Front Office & Reception" withRangeMark:UNKNOWN],[[CellModel alloc] initWith:@"Overall Quality of Room" withRangeMark:UNKNOWN],[[CellModel alloc] initWith:@"Check" withRangeMark:UNKNOWN],[[CellModel alloc] initWith:@"Response Time" withRangeMark:UNKNOWN],nil] atIndex:2];

    [modelList insertObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[[CellModel alloc] initWith:@"Room Decor" withRangeMark:UNKNOWN],nil] atIndex:3];


//    [modelList addObject: [[CellModel alloc] initWith:@"Service Speed" withRangeMark:UNKNOWN]];
//    [modelList addObject: [[CellModel alloc] initWith:@"Good Speed" withRangeMark:UNKNOWN]];
//    [modelList addObject: [[CellModel alloc] initWith:@"Confirmation Quality" withRangeMark:UNKNOWN]];
//    [modelList addObject: [[CellModel alloc] initWith:@"Quick Service in Reservetion" withRangeMark:UNKNOWN]];

//    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
//        CellModel *cellModel = [[CellModel alloc] init];
//        cellModel.range = UNKNOWN;
//        cellModel.itemText = @"";
//        [modelList addObject:cellModel];
//    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSLog(@"section: %ld - row : %ld - item text : %@", (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row, ((CellModel*)[[modelList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).itemText);

    [cell setupCellWithModel:[[modelList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    ((CustomButton*)cell.veryGoodButton).rowTag = indexPath.row;
    ((CustomButton*)cell.veryGoodButton).sectionTag = indexPath.section;

    ((CustomButton*)cell.goodButton).rowTag = indexPath.row;
    ((CustomButton*)cell.goodButton).sectionTag = indexPath.section;

    ((CustomButton*)cell.averageButton).rowTag = indexPath.row;
    ((CustomButton*)cell.averageButton).sectionTag = indexPath.section;

    ((CustomButton*)cell.belowAverageButton).rowTag = indexPath.row;
    ((CustomButton*)cell.belowAverageButton).sectionTag = indexPath.section;

    [cell.veryGoodButton addTarget:self action:@selector(veryGood:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell.goodButton addTarget:self action:@selector(good:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell.averageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(average:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell.belowAverageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(belowAverage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[modelList objectAtIndex:section] count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return sectionTitleList.count;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 18)];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, tableView.frame.size.width, 18)];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    NSString *string =[sectionTitleList objectAtIndex:section];

    [label setText:string];
    [view addSubview:label];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

    return view;
}

- (void) veryGood:(CustomButton*)sender {
    ((CellModel*)[[modelList objectAtIndex:sender.sectionTag] objectAtIndex:sender.rowTag]).range = VERY_GOOD;
    [self setCellDynamicly:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.rowTag inSection:sender.sectionTag] withCellModel:[[modelList objectAtIndex:sender.sectionTag] objectAtIndex:sender.rowTag]];
}

- (void) good:(CustomButton*)sender {
    ((CellModel*)[[modelList objectAtIndex:sender.sectionTag] objectAtIndex:sender.rowTag]).range = GOOD;
    [self setCellDynamicly:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.rowTag inSection:sender.sectionTag] withCellModel:[[modelList objectAtIndex:sender.sectionTag] objectAtIndex:sender.rowTag]];
}

- (void) average:(CustomButton*)sender {
    ((CellModel*)[[modelList objectAtIndex:sender.sectionTag] objectAtIndex:sender.rowTag]).range = AVERAGE;
    [self setCellDynamicly:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.rowTag inSection:sender.sectionTag] withCellModel:[[modelList objectAtIndex:sender.sectionTag] objectAtIndex:sender.rowTag]];
}

- (void) belowAverage:(CustomButton*)sender {
    ((CellModel*)[[modelList objectAtIndex:sender.sectionTag] objectAtIndex:sender.rowTag]).range = BELOW_AVERAGE;
    [self setCellDynamicly:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.rowTag inSection:sender.sectionTag] withCellModel:[[modelList objectAtIndex:sender.sectionTag] objectAtIndex:sender.rowTag]];
}

- (void)setCellDynamicly:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath withCellModel:(CellModel*)cellModel {
    TableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell prepareForReuse];
    [cell setupCellWithModel:cellModel];
}

@end
```

I think that it will work fine for you. Just do some change part of array init on code to dynamic :)

last appearance :

[image]

Comment: yes, thanks for update.i have one doubt, pls check my code, i updated.. in that you will find GNM and NM array , GNM contains section header names and NM contains rows related to sections.. everything comes from response like i posted in first comment .. here you added items to sectionTitleList and modelList static. but ,how it will work in my case..pls give me idea

Comment: just assign your response to arrays and use a dynamic way to do this.

Comment: got this error :  [__NSCFString itemText]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x165fa820

Comment: send me your project gkhnaydn16@hotmail.com

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 600;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

    sectionTitleList = [NSMutableArray<NSString*> new];
    for (NSString* sectionTitle in yourSectionResponseArray) {
        [sectionTitleList addObject: sectionTitle];
    }

    modelList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: [sectionTitleList count]];

    //your row title array has to be 2D array.
    for(int i = 0; i < [sectionTitleList count]; i++) {
        NSMutableArray* rowStringArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        for(NSString* rowTitle in [your2DRowResponseArray objectAtIndex:i]) {
             [rowStringArray addObject: rowTitle];
        }
        [modelList insertObject: rowStringArray];
    } 
}
```

May be this can help you.

Comment: i am getting warning in this line  ike : - Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSMutableArray *' to parameter of type 'CellModel * _Nonnull ...........  [modelList insertObject:rowStringArray atIndex:i];  ..  if i didn't add atIndex its showing error like this :-    No visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray<CellModel *>' declares the selector 'insertObject:'......    [modelList insertObject:rowStringArray];  ..  Any changes ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided us the API response details as requested earlier we are forced to use static value. Please replace sectionTitleList & modelList from the array API response. Please find the below code to be used to assign you API response to model created by @Gökhan Aydın .

```
sectionTitleList = @[@"RESERVATION",@"FRONT DESK",@"CASHIER",@"HOUSE KEEPING",@"COMMON"];
    modelList = @[
                 @[
                  @"Service Speed",
                  @"Good Service",
                  @"Confirmation quality",
                  @"Quick Service in Reservation"
                  ],
                 @[
                  @"Check In",
                  @"Happy on their Service",
                  @"Courtesey",
                  @"Quick Service at Checkin"
                  ],
                 @[
                  @"Front office & reception",
                  @"Overall Quality of Room",
                  @"Check",
                  @"Response time"
                  ],
                 @[
                  @"Room Decor",
                  @"Time taken to serveTime taken to serveTime taken t",
                  @"Bathroom",
                  @"Facilities in the Room",
                  @"Choice of menu",
                  @"Housekeeping",
                  @"Room Service"
                  ],
                 @[
                  @"Overall Comments",
                  @"Will you come back again"
                  ]
                 ];

        self.navigationItem.title = [modelList lastObject];
GNM = [sectionTitleList mutableCopy];
NM = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSArray *feedbacktitles in modelList) {
    if ([feedbacktitles isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        __block NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        [feedbacktitles enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *title, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
            FeedbackModel *model = [[FeedbackModel alloc]initWith:title withRangeMark:UNKNOWN];
            [tempArray addObject:model];
            if (idx ==  [feedbacktitles count] - 1 ) {
                *stop = TRUE;
                [self->NM addObject:tempArray];
                tempArray = [NSMutableArray new];
            }
        }];

    }
}
```

or by simple for loop

```
for (NSArray *feedbacktitles in modelList) {
        NSLog(@"%@",feedbacktitles);
        NSMutableArray* rowStringArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        if ([feedbacktitles isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            for(int i = 0; i < [feedbacktitles count]; i++) {
                NSString* rowTitle = [feedbacktitles objectAtIndex:i];
                FeedbackModel *model = [[FeedbackModel alloc]initWith:rowTitle withRangeMark:UNKNOWN];
                [rowStringArray addObject: model];
                if (i == [feedbacktitles count] - 1) {
                    [NM addObject: rowStringArray];
                    rowStringArray = [NSMutableArray new];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am bit confused about code in for-loop, can you make it in simple way, Thanks for update..